# How to add ftp put function in PyQT network ftp demo

Tags: python, ftp, pyqt, qtnetwork

I want to modify the pyqt network ftp demo to include an upload function, but I am failing. Could someone can show me how to do this?
I have tried to add this code, but it does not work. [Orignal Demo]https://github.com/Werkov/PyQt4/blob/master/examples/network/ftp/ftp.py

```
buttonBox.addButton(self.uploadButton,
            QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.ActionRole)
self.uploadButton = QtGui.QPushButton("upload")
self.uploadButton.clicked.connect(self.selectFile)

def selectFile(self):
    self.filename =QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
    up_fname = re.sub(r".*/","",self.filename)
    upload_file = QtCore.QFile(self.filename)
    self.ftp.put(upload_file, up_fname)
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Do you get an error message? Does the upload fail? What exactly happens?

Comment: @Cyber , not upload file and app crashed.